# terraform libvirt trouble with bridged network

Tags: terraform, kvm, libvirt

monday morning challenge for terraform experts ;-)

I have a problem in creating a KVM host with libvirt provider, when using a bridged network.
The network interface cannot receive dhcp info. However a `virt-install` with same bridged network works ok. The DHCP/DNS server is local on the network, I am not using the builtin DHCP server.

Below is the terraform to create network and guest....

```
# create KVM bridge network 
resource "libvirt_network" "kvm_network" {
  name = "kvmnet"
  mode = "bridge"
  bridge = "br0"
  autostart = "true"
}

# create kvm volume
resource "libvirt_volume" "generic-kvm-volume" {  
  name = "debian-141"
  pool = "tf"                                     
  source = "/var/kvm/images/debian11.img"
}                                                 

# Define KVM domain to create                     
resource "libvirt_domain" "generic-kvm-domain" {  
  name = "debian"
  vcpu = 1
  memory = 1024
                                                  
  network_interface {                             
    network_name   = "kvmnet"                    
    mac            = "de:3d:c0:a8:0a:8d"
  }                                               
  disk {                                          
    file = "/var/kvm/tf/debian-141"    
  }                                                
  console {                                        
    type = "pty"                                   
    target_type = "serial"                         
    target_port = "0"                              
  }                                                
  graphics {                                       
    type = "spice"                                 
    listen_type = "address"                        
    autoport = true                                
  }                                                
}
```

If I comment the "# Define KVM domain to create" block and re-run `terraform apply` to remove only the guest and then create a domain via `virt-install` (using the terraform defined network and volume) the interface comes up and is allocated the IP/Domain name as intended.

```
virt-install \                   
  --name debian-14 \             
  --memory 1024 \                
  --vcpus 2 \                    
  --disk /var/kvm/tf/debian-141 \
  --import \                     
  --network network=kvmnet \     
  --mac=de:3d:c0:a8:0a:8d \      
  --os-variant debian10
```

this alludes to the last block of terraform config as physical bridge/terraform bridge seems to be working as intended.

Notes:

- `wait_for_lease = true` times out
- I have looked at the `xml` for `kvmnet` for both instances and these are identical.

so hopefully a terraform expert can comment on this monday morning challenge ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE / SOLUTION:** Declaring `machine = "pc-q35-5.2"` resolved this problem. It was previously not set and defaulting to `pc-i440fx-5.2`.